# MATLAB/Octave: feval with vector input

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to put a function in feval(f,x) that has a vector as input
e.g.

```
function [ ret ] = f (x)
    ret = x(1)^2 - x(2)^2;
end
```

and

```
x = [1,2]
```

but octave always gives an error code:

```
`x' undefined near line 6 column 18
evaluating argument list element number 1
evaluating argument list element number 1
```

It seems feval can only evaluate numbers and not vectors. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a handle to your function and then call `feval` on the handle, passing it your vector as its argument:

```
h = @(x)myfun(x);
x = [1, 2];
y = feval(h, x);
```

I tried this out in Octave on your function and it seems to work.